# What is this chained ES6 arrow function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, redux, arrow-functions

I am creating an app using React, Redux.

Among them, I am making a Redux middleware,

There is a part that I do not understand.

Here is the code:

```
const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action => {

    console.log('currentState', store.getState());

    console.log('action', action);

    const result = next(action);

    console.log(', store.getState());
    console.log('\n'); 

    return result;
}

export default loggerMiddleware;
```

What is this arrow function `=> => =>`?
It does not make sense that the arrow function continues.

What does that mean?

Comment: An arrow function with a single expression automatically returns that value. `const x = foo => foo + "bar"`. So this returns a string when invoked. But now let's make `x` return a *function* that returns a string. `const x = foo => foo2 => foo + foo2 + "bar"`

Comment: It may be clearer if you put parentheses around the function being returned. `const x = foo => (foo2 => foo + foo2 + "bar")`

Answer (score 3):

The code below:

```
const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action => { 
    var result = /* .. */
    return result;
}
```

is the equivalent of:

```
const loggerMiddleware =  function(store) { 
    return function(next) {
        return function(action) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also add that this allows for chainging functions together. A simple example would be `add => x => y => x+y`, so when you are calling this, you can call `add(3)(5)` and end up with `8`. The advantage over a function that takes two parameters is that you can pass this around, for example, `[20, 35, 42].map(add(5))` is easier to read and maintain than `x => x + 5`. Especially since you can reuse it, e.g., if you have `shippingTax = add(5)` it's even easier. The topic her is "currying" and that's the basis of it - have functions that take one parameter and return another function

Answer (score 3):

This is a technique (called currying) that replaces a single function which takes some arguments with multiple functions each taking a part of those arguments, for example:

```js
    const f1 = (x, b) => x + b;
    const f2 = x => b => x + b;
    
    const f1Result = f1(1, 2);
    // we can construct f2's result in multiple steps if we want because it returns a function, this can be helpful.
    let f2Result = f2(1);
    f2Result = f2Result(2);

    console.log('f1Result', f1Result);
    console.log('f2Result', f2Result);
```

You can also read [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/534) for more insight of the rationale behind this decision, mainly:

> Sometimes we want to associate some local state with store and next

Comment: I actually wrote that in another comment :) Anyway, to make the example more concrete, imagine if `f2` was called `add` and instead of `let f2result = f2(1)` you name the variable `addShippingTax = add(1)`. That's less abstract and directly shows why you might want this. If the shipping tax changes, you just have to modify that, for example. You could also derive many other functions `addHandlingTax`, `includeOverseasCharges`, `hiddenFeeForDeveloperCoffee`, etc - you don't have to make an entirely new function for each that just does `x+1`, `x+6`, `x+42` when you already have `x=>y=>x+y`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrow function is the replacement of 8 characters 'function' keyword. you don't need to write return within your function when you are using arrow function.

As per Javascript best practices try to use when you are making service calls. It is used as function keyword short hand.

For more on this see a good sample on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions